# How to create pop up in phone gap

Tags: android, cordova, popupwindow

Helo,
Is there a possibility to click on button and show a popupover and inside it there is two buttons. When i click on each of them , i have an alert.
If there isn't a possibility with a popupover is there a possibilty of any other popup window?
My Android application is developped in phonegap
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the cordova dialogue api.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/blob/master/doc/index.md

I think you are looking for the navigator.notification.confirm feature.

Using this feature you can display a popup with multiple options for the user to tap on.

The index of the button the user taps on is returned to the confirmCallback, so you can handle the user input.

Answer (score 0):

navigator.notification.confirm(message, onConfirm, [button1], [button2]);

```
function onConfirm(buttonIndex) {
    alert('You selected button ' + buttonIndex);
}
```

perform operations based on buttonIndex.